# How do I display ${'None'} in a Django Mako template?

Tags: python, django, mako

I am trying to show words from a list of possible values (including 'None', 'Little', and 'More') on a Django website using Mako-templates.  Only two of the three words are actually rendered. 'None' gets interpreted as None and is converted to an empty string when I call ${variable}.

In troubleshooting, I determined that actually writing ${'None'} in the mako template returns an empty string to the browser.

Is there a way to get the mako template to print this string?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `${"None"}` is rendered as an empty string? It is rendered as `None` for me. Did you happen to forget to put `"` around `None`? in `${"None"}`?

Comment: If indeed you have `${"None"}` rendered as empty string, what do you see if you use `${"None"|n}`?

Comment: I checked my test, and I was using quotation marks.  Your recommendation for |n worked perfectly!  Is that a python, django, or mako construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mako has a filter system which uses `|` operator to apply escape filters to `${}`.

Without any configuration Mako by default would use `unicode` filter implicitly. Though you can always change the default filter Mako uses by setting the [`default_filters`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#the-default-filters-argument) argument.

The [`n` filter](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#expression-filtering) disable all default filtering; only filters specified in the local expression tag will be applied.

So by default, Mako *should* render `${"None"}` as `None` instead of empty string. The fact that it only works for you when adding `n` filter suggests that you have probably set `default_filters` to some other filter that escaped string `None` into empty string. `n` will fix it, but before you use it you should probably dig a bit further to see if `default_filters` has been set somewhere in your code.

**WARNING**: `n` filter shouldn't be applied normally for any user (the user of your websites that is) input, because no-escaping means you are vulnerable to a range of attacks such as the XSS.

Comment: Thank you!  That is a very helpful explanation.  I will do some investigating on my filter settings.

Comment: I did some more investigation.  I inherited some code from the previous developer.  He used a custom filter that changed any input equal to "None" to "".  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!